Bond future deliveries
More looking for a confirmation here, if someone knowledgeable on the subject could confirm/correct I would be grateful:
I often hear authors/commentators stating that say I have to deliver a not-CTD bond into a futures contract I am short, my loss will be the gross basis of that bond (assuming basis has not converged fully). Its really conversion factor (cf) x gross basis though, isn't it, assuming I'm holding cf futures short ?  (I get that it's just a notional adjustment, but assuming I can clear out the tail of my cash position at flat - I am not sure how I could lose the full gross basis).
Thank you!
Edit : basis has 'not' converged as the bond is not the CTD.

Gross basis is just the difference between the bond price and the converted futures price:
$$
B_{\text{GROSS}} = P - F \times CF
$$
In some cases, there can be multiple bonds which have a possibility of being the CTD at expiry. What you gain/lose will be the gross basis. It's just a simple relationship that show's what you'll gain/lose if you decided to buy a bond today and short the equivalent futures contract.
You can read more here.

The gross basis of a non-CTD bond can 100% be negative. As an example, look at the GB on the bond 91282CGM7. This is in the CTD basket but the worst to deliver. It has a gross basis of -3.5132875.

This comment or the answer don't really address the question. I know gross basis can be negative.. I did specify..in the delivery period. In fact the answer, up until the edit was just incorrect. Now it's just stating basics and contradicting itself.

Prior to deleting your comment which is not good practice, you implied otherwise. I see that I've contradicted myself following the edit, however I'm not sure what you're asking because you're asking if the loss should be cf * gross basis, but it's not because gb represents the spread between spot and futures. If you're asking if it changes in the delivery period, why would it?

Deleted my comment as you amended your answer and it didn't follow. Why I'm suggesting it changes in the delivery period is that I only deliver cf amount of bonds into cf futures (which I am short). (1-cf), the tail of the position  is cleared in the spot market (hypothetically at flat).

I think you're misunderstanding how the conversion factor works. The conversion factor standardises the futures and effectively converts the 6% coupon on the deliverable futures to the coupon of the deliverable bond. So while you may hold 1 future contract and 1 bond, at delivery, you still have to deliver 1 bond, but the cash you'll get in exchange for this will be $F \times CF$, not $F$.

Sure. That makes sense. Therefore, in a typical basis position the set up is long 1 unit of spot vs 'cf' futures short. Now as soon I want to make delivery we go to a situation where I need to deliver 'cf' bonds into my 'cf' short futures. My net pnl is cf x (fut x cf - spot) = cf x (gross basis) x -1. Agree ? Hence my initial comment - you lose cf of (x) gross basis

No, at expiry, you're still delivering 1 unit of spot Vs 'cf' futures. This relationship does not change. So your net PnL is $\text{Spot} - CF \times F$, which is the gross basis. For simplicity, suppose CF = 0.8. The second scenario would imply you've bought 0.8 bonds and sold 0.8 futures.

I would recommend reading the link, it should help in understanding the basis

OK. I always thought 1 lot of short futures is for 100k nominal bonds delivery. I'll rethink and come back. Thanks.

Found this thread and the doc- https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/45523/68819, I think my statement and thinking is correct. Maybe the question wasn't clear.

Ah ok, I see now. This arises from the fact that prior to the first intent date, a trader trading the spread will sell CF Futures for every bond to match notional, but after the first intent date, the notional value of the futures contract effectively changes, leaving them with tail. Holding to expiry, trading 1-to-1 would return the GB as PnL but between this point, I guess the positions would not be perfectly hedged due to the different notionals.

Yep. Not sure why the question got down voted when it's actually quite a subtle and useful point/common misconception
